# vb.net Form wont start it just closes

Tags: vb.net

I set my first form to my login page but when i start it, It closes immediately

```
Private Sub login_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Dim ToolTip1 As New ToolTip()
    ToolTip1.AutoPopDelay = 5000
    ToolTip1.InitialDelay = 1000
    ToolTip1.ReshowDelay = 500
    ToolTip1.ShowAlways = True
    ToolTip1.SetToolTip(Me.txt_pword, "Enter password here!")
    ToolTip1.SetToolTip(Me.txt_username, "Enter username here!")
End Sub

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btn_login2.Click
    dbconn = New SqlConnection
    dbconn.ConnectionString = ("Data Source=JENELIE\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=LDESfeeding_DB;User ID=sa;Password=Jenelie19")
    Dim reader As SqlDataReader
    Try
        dbconn.Open()
        Dim sql As String
        sql = "select * from auth_pword where Password = '" & txt_pword.Text & "' and username = '" & txt_username.Text & "' "
        dbcomm = New SqlCommand(sql, dbconn)
        reader = dbcomm.ExecuteReader
        Dim ctr As Integer
        ctr = 0
        While reader.Read
            ctr = ctr + 1
        End While
        If ctr = 1 Then
            MessageBox.Show("Login Successful!")
            homepage.Show()
            Me.Close()
        Else
            MessageBox.Show("Incorrect Username or Password!")
        End If
        dbconn.Close()
    Catch ex As SqlException
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
    End Try
End Sub
```

End Class
That's the whole code in that form. I don't know what's causing it to close.
I tried to change the `.Close()` to `.Hide()` still nothing changes.

Comment: Please update your post and remove your DB credentials and I would change them as well. Never post this info on the web for anyone to see. Aside from that look into `Using` statements and `SQL Parameters`... Are you saying the startup form is this class?

Comment: `ToolTip1.SetToolTip(Me.txt_pword, "Enter password here!")
    ToolTip1.SetToolTip(Me.txt_username, "Enter username here!")` What is `Me.txt_pword` and `Me.txt_username`?

Comment: On another note comment out the last `ToolTip1.SetToolTip` and see if that works. I think the standard WinForms `ToolTip` can be only targeted to one control, but you can handle the mouse over on the controls to use that tooltip...

Comment: @video.baba I would assume `TextBox`'s from his current code.

Comment: @Codexer i dont why but restarting my laptop solves it, but when I change a bit of code from any form, starting the project would immediately terminate it

Comment: Are you changing the code while your application is running?

Comment: I think your classmate posted the same odd bit of code incrementing a counter in a While reader.Read. Where did this come from? Just check If reader.HasRows.

Comment: Don't concatenate sql queries. Use parameters. Also do not store passwords as plain text.

Comment: If your user validation is successful and you close the form, how is your connection going to be closed?

Comment: @Mary im not changing codes while im debugging.

Comment: @Mary there were no problems in the code, everytime I change some codes in any other forms of my project, even if I started on a different form, it will start for a sec and then immediately stop debugging